# How to make nodes on branchy TikZ chain lay on regular grid (trangular or square) automatically?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-chains

How to ensure that nodes on chain with branches (generated using `chains` library) are laid out on regular grid, regardless of node shape?

I am interested in automatic placement on triangular or rectangular grid, if possible without use of matrices.

Example: in the following diagram nodes are laid out on rectangular grid:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,
    every node/.style={on chain, join, draw},
    every join/.style=<-]
  \node {A};
  \node {B};
  \begin{scope}[start branch=foo]
    \node [on chain=going below right] {E};
    \node (F) {F};
  \end{scope}
  \node {C};
  \node {D};
  \node [join=with F] {G};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But if I change node style to circle or rounded rectangle with a minimum size of 6mm the layout changes to *almost* on triangular grid.

Comment: I didn't check it but maybe `on grid` option of `positioning` library play nicely with chains.

Comment: You can look at `placed` chain instead of `going` chain (cf. p.286 of pgfmanual v2.10).

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What do you mean automatic placement on a regular grid? Have you tried @percusse’s `on grid` suggestion? That actually does place the nodes on a grid as it only uses the `center` anchors, as opposed to the `west` and the `east` anchors in the default `going right` option. The `below right` option uses the `south east` and `north west` anchors which can be attributed for the placement of the circular nodes.